# SES from EC2: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client - what data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, amazon-ses

I can send email from my EC2 via the CLI, but after successful sending, it times out with `421 Timeout waiting for data from client`. My question: what would the client send back, and on what port?

My guess is that my security group has a port locked down that is preventing a response back, but I tried opening 465 inbound (which is where I send outbound) and that didn't solve it.

As I said - the email goes out (I received a test via the CLI), but I can't enable SMTP sending in my PHP application because it keeps timing out waiting for a response. Thank you!

Comment: You need to be hitting SES on 465, or 587, not 25, if 25 is what you are doing now.  Assuming you are not using 25, it sounds like this error points to your mail library not properly closing the connection with `QUIT\r\n`.  The error potentially means *timed out waiting for you to do* **something** rather than waiting for anything specific... but using port 25 does  not work without additional steps, while the others should be fine.